# Equipping tire pump with pressure gauge

Tags: tires

Is it possible to add a pressure gauge to a tire pump that has no pressure gauge? I was googling for pump hoses with built-in pressure gauge but couldn't find any. I was also looking for pressure gauges that can be attached to either end of the hose of the tire pump but found none.

Comment: Are you talking about adding one to a compressor line? If so, look for *tire chuck with air gauge* and I think you'll see what you're looking for.

Comment: No, I want to add one to a simple mechanic pump, the kind you can push with your hands or your foot.

Comment: There are [hand/foot pumps](http://www.amazon.com/Pressure-Bicycle-Alloy-Floor-Gauge/dp/B005LABW2E) which come with a pressure gauge attached.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm looking for a way to add a pressure gauge to my old pump rather than getting a new pump.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add one by adding a t-piece into the high-pressure line and adding a gauge to the T. I'd have hoped that someone would have made a ready-made one that wouldn't involve modifying the pump, but I can't find one, so I think you'd have to make your own.

On that basis, you'd need:

- a t-piece with the same internal diameter as your pump's air line
- another bit of hose with the same internal diameter
- a suitable gauge

Something like this [Draper](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0002GV286/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=569136327&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B0002GV3DA&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1T9GXM73WCM1ZHG3F2MJ) gauge with it's own flexible hose would provide both the latter two, so you'd just need a suitable t-piece (I'm not sure of the correct internal diameter, I'd guess 5 or 6 mm, but don't have anything to hand to measure)